# $sce.TrustAsUrl not Working

Tags: javascript, html, regex, angularjs, ngsanitize

I am trying to create an app using angularjs where the input is taken from the input box and is displayed. It is similar to a chat. So the input can contain urls and I am converting them to links with the help of [Autolinker.js](https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js)  which I found in this SO question [How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links) .
To inject html in angular binding I am using [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) but I want only the urls to be changed to links and anything like 2<3 should be printed as 2<3 but should not be read as HTML tag.

I even used [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) but it didnt work. It is giving an error `Parse Error` with 2<3

There is a better option using `linky` but it is not able to convert urls without http.
Fiddle with the 3 options:http://jsfiddle.net/JY3Za/58/ (PS:Here I just used a RegEx for testing)

So what would be the best way to inject html in angular while using the Autolinker.js so that only  and  tags are allowed but anything other than these should be displayed as plain text..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you where passing the wrong arguments to your

```
$sce.trustAsHtml
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JY3Za/59/

Comment: thanks for the answer but this is not working for trustAsUrl which should accept only <a> and <img> tags..to prevent XSS attacks but if u give <hr> as input it shouldnt show a horizontal line

Comment: $sce.trustAsUrl is used to retrieve resources, has nothing to do with tags display, so maybe i missunderstood what you where trying to do, but i though it was to present links in your box from the input, in with case an html tag needs to be rendered using trustAsHtml

Comment: any idea how to allow only <a> and <img> tags..?

Comment: well, the <a> tag is generated by you, so if someone types an html tag you should either string the tag or not use it at all, only links right? and in links you can determine whether to display an image or a anchor based on the file extension

Comment: thanks, well i did the same replaced all the unwanted < back to &lt; so that  they wouldnt be treated as html tags but would be displayed as <, but still i feel this is not 100% secure

Comment: i just realize you don't need to, you just need to return an sce if the imput string matches a regexp validtion right? so if it doesn't you return the sanitized text instead. that way you don't have to worry about striping html tags because sanitize will take care of that for you unless you want to turn actual a tags from the input as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54988/discussion-between-srinath-and-dayan-moreno-leon).